# How to avoid Clozure freeing when I paste into the Listener?

Tags: ide, common-lisp

Sometimes I do a paste of text into the wrong place in the Listener window while using Clozure.  When that happens a window from AltConsole pops up and informs me

```
> Error: Can't modify protected buffer region.
> While executing: HEMLOCK-INTERFACE:EDITOR-ERROR, in process    Initial(0).
> Type :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> Type :? for other options.
1 >
```

The problem is I don't know how to get out of the AltConsole window without Clozure freezing.  Aside from this not being too friendly to new users, how do I get out of the AltConsole and back to working in Clozure?

Comment: What happens if you do what it says (type `:pop` at that prompt)?

Comment: Nohting useful: 1 > :POP
> Error: Failed assertion: (EQL (SLOT-VALUE GUI::TS 'GUI::EDIT-COUNT) 0)
> While executing: CCL::%ASSERTION-FAILURE, in process Initial(0).
> Type :GO to continue, :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> If continued: test the assertion again.
> Type :? for other options.